# unzip files with yesterday date to 'other' location not working

Tags: directory, zip

I can unzip just fine like this

```
find /file/location -mtime -1 -print -exec unzip -o {} \;
```

But I get an error if I try to make it unzip to another location `/home/username`:

```
find /file/location -mtime -1 -print -exec unzip -d /home/username;
```

What am I doing incorrectly?

Comment: Possibly related: [Understanding the -exec option of `find`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/389705/understanding-the-exec-option-of-find)

Answer (score 2):

You need pass fileName to unzip it, also escape the special character `;`.

```
find /file/location -mtime -1 -type f -exec unzip {} -d /home/username \;
```